# None of my citations work! Please help!

Tags: citing

Something changed for no obvious reason as I was working on this. My citations compiled just fine, but now I get an error for every citation I have. I'm using BibTeX. Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{WUbiblio,WUthesis}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\begin{document}

\title{blah}
\author{blah}
\thesissupervisor{blah}

\maketitle

\newpage

\begin{center}
\textbf{Presentations and publications}
\begin{description}
\end{description}
\end{center}

\begin{acknowledgments}
Don't need to show.
\end{acknowledgments}

\begin{abstract}
Don't need to show.
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{introduction}
\chapter{Background and Theory}
\input{background}
\section{Structure and Function of Myosin}
\input{structureandfunction}
\section{Actin}
\input{actin}
\section{Myosin's Chemomechanical Cycle}
\input{chemocycle}
\section{Gating and Processivity of a Myosin VI Dimer}
\input{gating}
\section{The H246R Mutation}
\input{H246R}
\section{The Optical Trap}
\input{trap}
\section{Single and Three Bead Assays}
\input{forces}
\chapter{Gating's Dependence on Force in Myosin VI}
\section{Step Size, Dwell Time, and Interhead Distance}
\input{stepsanddwells}
\section{Methods of Analysis}
\subsection{Hand-Picking and Data Selection}
\input{handpicking}
\subsection{Chi-Squared Method}
\input{chisquared}
\subsection{Identifying Transitions}
\input{transitions}
\subsection{The Goodness Score}
\input{goodnessscore}
\subsection{Interhead Distance Calculations}
\input{interheaddistance}
\subsection{Pearson's Correlation Test}
\input{pearson}
\subsection{Previous Results}
\input{travisresults}
%\input{methods}

\chapter{Results}

Needed

\chapter{Conclusions}

Needed

%\bibliographystyle{urcsbiblio}
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{thesisbib}

\appendix
\include{notebook}

\end{document}
```

Here is the .bib file:

```
@article{Altman,
    author={D. Altman},
    title={Regulation of the molecular motor protein myosin vi},
    journal={Stanford University Doctoral Dissertation},
    year={2006}}

@article{Sweeney,
    author={HL Sweeney},
    title={How Myosin VI Coordinates its Heads during Processive Movement},
    journal={The EMBO Journal},
    volume={26},
    year={2004},
    pages={2682-2692}}

@article{Baer,
    author={T. Baer},
    title={Investigation Molecular Strain within a Myosin VI Dimer},
    journal={Willamette University Undergraduate Thesis},
    year={2013},
    pages={1-34}}

@article{Sweeney07,
    author={HL Sweeney and Anne Houdusse},
    title={myosin VI Rewrites the Rules for Myosin Motors},
    journal={Cell},
    volume={141},
    year={2010},
    pages={573-582}}

@article{Reisler,
    author={E. Reisler},
    title={Actin molecular structure and function},
    journal={Curr. Opin. Cell. Biol.},
    volume={1},
    year={1993},
    pages={41}}

@article{Sivar,
    author={JA Spudich and S. Sivaramakrishnan},
    title={Myosin VI: An Innovative Motor that Challenged the Swinging Lever Arm Hypothesis},
    journal={Nature Reviews. Molecular Cell Biology},
    volume={11},
    year={2010},
    pages={128-37}}

@article{Spu12,
    author={JA Spudich},
    title={One path to understanding energy transduction in biological systems},
    journal={Nature Reviews},
    volume={18},
    year={2012},
    pages={1478-1482}}

@article{MyosinMotion2001,
    author={JA Spudich and D Altman and HL Sweeney},
    title={The mechanics of myosin VI motion and its load-induced anchoring},
    journal={Cell},
    volume={116},
    year={2004},
    pages={737-749}}

      @article{Bates,
    author={Genevieve Bates},
    title={Project: Molecular mechanics of telokin},
    journal={Lauzon Lab},
    year={2003},
    pages={1152}}

@article{LuiseC,
    author={Luise C},
    title={Myosin VI: Roles of a minus end-directed actin motor in cells},
    journal={Journal of Cell Biology},
        year={2000},
        pages={121-126}}


@article{Dan14,
    author={Rebekah Daniel},
    title={Elucidating the role of myosin vi in retinal pigment epithelium cell phagocytosis},
    journal={Willamette University Undergraduate Thesis},
    year={2014},
    pages={11}}

@article{ea03,
    author={SA Mohiddin et al.},
    title={Novel association of hypertrophic cardiomyopathy, sensorineural deafness, and a mutation in unconventional  myosin VI (myo6)},
    journal={Journal of Medical Genetics},
    volume={41},
    year={2004},
    pages={309-314}}


@article{trapping,
    author = {Keir C Neuman and Steven M Block},
    title = {Optical Trapping}, 
    journal = {US National Library of Medicine National Institutes of Health Search},
    year={2004}}

@article{WLC,
    author={A.L. Wells and A.W. Lin and L. Chen and D. Safer and S.M. Calin and T. Hasson abd B.O. Carragher and R.A. Milligan and H.L Sweeney },
    title={Myosin vi is an actin-based motor that moves backwards},
    journal={Nature},
    volume={401},
    year={1999},
    pages={505}}

@article{altproposal,
    author = {D. Altman},
    title = {Application for Murdock College Research Program for Life Sciences},   
    journal = {Research Grant Proposal},
    year={2013},
    pages={3}}

     @article{Block,
    author = {Keir C. Neuman and Steven M. Block},
    title = {Optical trapping}, 
    journal = {AIP},
    volume={75},
    year={2013},
    pages={4}}

@misc{Cruz,
    author = {De La Cruz et al.},
    title = {Kinetic mechanism and regulation of Myosin VI},
    journal={Journal of Biological Chemistry},
    volume={276},
    year = {2001},
    pages={32373-32381}}    

@misc{Muller,
    author = {L.S. Milescu and P.R. Selvin and F. Sachs},
    title = {Maximum likelihood estimation of molecular motor kinetics from staircase dwell time sequences},
    journal={Biophysical Journal},
    volume={99},
    year = {2010},
    pages={3864}}

@misc{Houdusse,
    author = {HL Sweeney and A Houdusse},
    title = {What can myosin VI do in cells?},
    journal={Curr Opin Cell Biol.},
    volume={19},
    year = {2007},
    pages={57-66}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please reduce your document that il become really minimal. As is, we cant compile them. Do you run `BibTeX` twice and then `LaTeX`?

Comment: Off-topic: Your bibliographic entries are full of errors, typos, and sloppy settings. If you value your thesis and want to be taken seriously as a researcher by your peers, do take the time to fix these issues.

Comment: no one can run your example since it just inputs files not shown, and you gave no indication of what error you got. That makes it hard to offer any help.